# Science Fiction Anthology of the 70's or early 80's

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a science fiction anthology. I remember two short stories in the book. The first had a main character named E and the story ends with "It just goes to show you, a flatter E will get you nowhere." The last story of the book has a post-apocalypse story about a man in a fortress and a girl who begs to be let in. He finally lets her in and then lets her that a bath. Later he is eating dinner stating how rare it is to have meat, implying he ate the girl. Also in the first story there seems to be something about changing from 3 dimensions to 2 dimensions leading to the 'Flatter' part of the pun.

Comment: A really bad pun implies Spider Robinson.

Comment: @Spencer Or Isaac Asimov.

Comment: @user14111 -- or part of a Ferdinand Feghoot anecdote? (Feghoot was created by Reginald Bretnor.)

Comment: Or Roger Zelazny.

Comment: I did a few Google searches for it and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, I read up on Feghoot and I remember it fitting the pattern of a short story leading to a pun (punchline.)